# MVC Trace.TraceInformation logging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I implemented Trace.TraceInformation.  Where does this log the information to?  Is there a window in VS 2010 that shows this or is there a file that it writes to?

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
{
    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information will be passed to elements of [Trace.Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.listeners.aspx) collection, which by default contains [DefaultTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.aspx)

To enable tracing, add the /d:TRACE flag to the compiler command line when you compile your code, or add #define TRACE to the top of your file.

To specify trace output file you may add `TextWriterTraceListener` to Listeners in your config:

```
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
    <listeners>
      <remove name="Default" />
      <add name="myListener"  type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"    initializeData="c:\myListener.log" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```